# How do I remove Ubuntu from a partition and reuse the partition for another distro?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uninstall

Ubuntu has been giving me a lot of trouble with frequent freezing and I can't seem to fix it so I wanted to remove Ubuntu and try another distribution. I was thinking of either Elementary OS or Linux Mint.

However I'm not sure how to properly do this so any information would be very helpful!

Currently I'm dual-booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu and using grub as the boot manager.

Comment: Use the installer of the other distro to formatt all Ubuntu partitions, then use the free space to install another distro. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If you're using testing version or latest version, I suggest you to
   use ubuntu 12.04 LTS, it's very stable release, and has matured over
   time. Your system won't freeze as frequently*.
*And after that if some problem exist, ask it here, you'll get answers
   very easily*

---

Here is answer if you want to install mint/elemenntryOS

Go to terminal and write

```
user@localhost:~$ sudo blkid
sudo] password for user10: 

/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="abcd" UUID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" TYPE="ntfs"  
/dev/sda5: UUID="72ab4798-8754-41ac-a483-794fd40f5201" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="7dabbc24-d018-4a6f-b5f7-c5df6d110ae6" TYPE="ext4"
```

- Write down the name of partition Where you see type is ext4/ext3, that would be ubuntu partition.
- In above output it would be /dev/sda6
- Download the Hybrid ISO of whatever OS you  want to install.

---

- Now make a bootable drive using any software, I prefer 
   [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)  make a bootable drive.
  There are many tutorial out there to make bootable pendrive.
- Boot the system using bootable pendrive now and while installing the system choose advanced partitioning option.
- Now format the drive with the name in our output that would be /dev/sda6
- Format the drive, and just install system now

Note: Just formatting ubuntu partition and not installing any other distro will lead your computer to unusable state, you'll not be able to boot the system untill you install grub using live cd

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this. I'll post again so others can see how it went.

Comment: I tried to install elementary os luna using this method, however I must've screwed something up because now I can't boot into either elementary or windows. Currently using the elementary os live cd.

I had separate partitions for the root and home drives so i deleted those and partitioned the free space again. Then i installed the boot loader to the efi boot drive. After this i couldn't boot.

Comment: I managed to boot back into windows after running boot repair several times with different settings but no sign of elementary os.

Comment: Found out what the problem was: Elementary OS Luna doesn't support an efi bootloader so I had to reinstall using a legacy partition.

Comment: sorry for replying late. !
nice...you solved most of the problem by yourself, this is how I learned.. :)